# Can I conda install an alpha or beta version of Python?

Tags: python, conda

At time of writing, alpha version `3.8.0a4` of python is available.  I would like to do some testing in a conda env before it is GA (for both educational purposes and to satisfy some curiosities).

When trying to conda install 3.8 I am getting a `PackagesNotFoundError` error.  Are alpha/beta versions of python simply unavailable through conda channels or is there perhaps an alternate conda channel where this might be found?

I know the latest version can be found on python.org in downloads/release but was really hoping for availability in a conda channel, if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

3.8.0a3 can be downloaded using `conda-forge`, which is a custom channel for conda. You can see the package listed [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python), with version 3.8.0a3 being labelled as `pre-3.8`. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like 3.8.0a4 is available yet.

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/pre-3.8 python
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/pull/259) on conda-forge for adding 3.8.0a4.

Comment: This looks very promising, although didnt work at initial try:

`Solving environment: failed`
`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:`
`  - python -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.6,<2.0a0']`
`  - python -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1']`
`...`

Comment: Note - this could actually be an issue with the way the internal conda repo is setup, and not with your instructions.  Thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: You could try adding conda-forge as a channel, as shown [here](http://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html#how-can-i-install-packages-from-conda-forge).

Comment: @user9074332 the issue is likely that you can't install this in an existing env because the other packages in there don't have compatible versions available. Instead, create a new env: `conda create -n py38 -c conda-forge/label/pre-3.8 python`

Comment: @Mark Right you are :).  Installing into a new env worked perfectly.  `conda create -n py38 -c https://artifactoryurl/conda-forge/label/pre-3.8 python`.

Comment: doing so offers `python 3.7` for me, both for `pre-3.8` and for `prerelease`. I'm on ubuntu `16.04`. Could this be a problem ?

Comment: First add the conda-forge channel `conda config --add channels conda-forge` then `conda create -n new-environment-name -c conda-forge/label/pre-3.8 python`. For other labels visit `https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python/labels`

Comment: Hey old question, but what are my best options for when the version I'm after isn't in conda-forge; do I need to open an issue there or is there any way of basically creating my own channel to install python 3.10 within an environment?